# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Tags: lista, condiciones, float, indices

```
 if (L2[INI]>L2[FIN]):
```

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Comment: si quieren el codigo lo puedo compartir sin problema

Comment: Pues el error parece claro, los índices que estás usando, INI y FIN, deben ser declarados como enteros (integers) en lugar de float.

Comment: como hago eso xd, soy nuevo en python :((

Comment: gracias viejo, ya corregi el error, cambie los ints por floats. gracias